# how to escape { in mybatis mapper.xml when execute maven archetype generate

Tags: maven, velocity, maven-archetype

Because we're now using spring+mybatis to develop project, so I want to create a maven archetype that is could generate a blank project with some demo code and test code to tell newbies how to use spring+mybaits and how to write unit test. But now I meet some problem, in `archetype-resources` there is a `archetype-resources/src/main/resources/sql/myapp/DemoUser.xml`,

```
<insert id="insertUser" useGeneratedKeys="true"
        keyProperty="id">
    insert into demo_user (mobile,nick) values (#{mobile},#{nick})
</insert>
```

after execute `mvn archetype:generate ...` it becomes

```
insert into demo_user (mobile,nick) values (#mobile,#nick)
```

then I tried below manner to escape `{` but failed,
in `archetype-resources/pom.xml` head add

```
#set( ${startbrace} = "{" )
```

then modify `DemoUser.xml`

```
insert into demo_user (mobile,nick) values (#${startbrace}mobile},#${startbrace}nick})
```

but actually it generate below code

```
insert into demo_user (mobile,nick) values (#${startbrace}#obile},#${startbrace}#ick})
```

So I'm very confused about this situation. I want to know how to escape `{` correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It may depends upon the version of Velocity you are using.

With Velocity 1.7+, the original problem does not occur (`(#{mobile},#{nick})` is properly rendered as is), and your workaround is also working as well.

I did not try to reproduce your problem with an older Velocity version, but I think that the problem comes from the fact you're using double quotes in your assignation. So you should try:

```
#set( ${startbrace} = '{' )
```

Single-quoted content is **not** parsed, so it should definitely work, even with old Velocity versions.

Comment: Thanks! I tried change to Single-quoted but it not works. And how to specify velocity version when execute `mvn archetype:generate ...`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried below way to solve it. In `src/main/resources/archetype-resources/pom.xml` head add

```
#set( $P = '#' )
```

then in `DemoUser.xml`

```
insert into demo_user (mobile,nick) values (${P}{mobile},${P}{nick})
```

Refer: http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#escaping-invalid-vtl-references

```
#set( $D = '$' )
${D}{my:invalid:non:reference}
```